# Exclude selected packages in jar command - build script

Tags: java, ant

My project structure has these base packages.

- a.b.c.core
- a.b.c.web
- a.b.c.common

And core,web,common packages will have sub packages. I have compiled all the java files under src dir and copied the class files to a dir.

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}/myapp" debug="true">
  <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
  <classpath refid="ant.classpath" />
</javac>
```

Now i want to build a jar say core.jar with class files belonging to a.b.c.core and its subpackages. Similarly a web.jar and common.jar. Can someone give a sample code for jar task to accompolish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than *excluding* specific areas, I'd just *include* the ones you want:

```
<jar destfile="core.jar"
     basedir="${build}/myapp"
     includes="a/b/c/core/**"
/>
<jar destfile="common.jar"
     basedir="${build}/myapp"
     includes="a/b/c/common/**"
/>
<jar destfile="web.jar"
     basedir="${build}/myapp"
     includes="a/b/c/web/**"
/>
```

The [`jar` task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) is pretty good though... if the above doesn't do what you want, then that should help you.

Comment: Indeed, the jar task page has examples showing how to combine includes and excludes.